# HTML5 Regual Expression Needed

Tags: javascript, regex, html

I need HTML5  regular Expression to match the following

CC/YYYY/MM/DDDDDDDD

**CC**: Two character country code (case insensitive)

**YYYY**: 4 digits year

**MM**: Two Digits Month

**DDDDDDDD**: 8 Digits Invoice Number

I tried the following which is working with PHP and javascript, but I do need it to run on HTML 5:

```
 ^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]\/\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{8}$
```

Please show a full example, ie:

```
 <input tabindex="5" type="Text" name="description" size="19" required pattern="^[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z]\/\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{8}^"  placeholder="CC/YYYY/MM/XXXXXXXX">
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: <input tabindex="5" type="Text" name="description" size="19" required pattern="^[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z]\/\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{8}^"  placeholder="CC/YYYY/MM/XXXXXXXX"></td>

Comment: Your pattern is OK, see https://jsfiddle.net/ff1syanw/ Just remove the unnecessary `^` and `$` (they are added automatically).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Would you mind posting that as an answer?

Comment: @iismathwizard: Isn't it the same pattern? After the edit, I see that the HTML pattern attribute value contains a typo - `^` at the end. And a "wild" `+` quantifier.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew No, actually. If you look at the input element op made, the pattern starts `[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z]...`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I tried this, it won't work, I don't know what is the problem, this is why I asked for help

Comment: @MohammadAwniAli Then your issue isn't with the regular expression; it has to be something else.

Comment: @MohammadAwniAli: Did you put the `<input>` element into a `<form>`? Try [this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/bqxh48f6/1/)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that was exactly what I was looking for, it was included in a form before, and every thing was correct, but your pattern is correct and do the needful, just pasted the pattern into my code and it works like magic, thanks :)

Comment: Well, that is strange. I will post with explanations, but  I am still not sure why it did not work. What browser were you trying it in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remember that [HTML5 pattern attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/single-page.html#the-pattern-attribute) accepts a regex pattern as a string that will be anchored by default with `^(?:` and `)$`.

> The regular expression language used for this attribute is the same as that used in JavaScript, except that **the pattern attribute is matched against *the entire value*, not just any subset** (somewhat as if **it implied a `^(?:` at the start of the pattern and a `)$` at the end**).

That means, you do not have to escape the `/` slashes, and you actually do not have to double backslashes.

Use

```
pattern="[a-zA-Z]{2}/\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{8}"
```

```css
input:valid {
  color: green;
}
input:invalid {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input tabindex="5" value="en/1234/05/12345678" type="Text" name="description" size="19" required pattern="[a-zA-Z]{2}/\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{8}"  placeholder="CC/YYYY/MM/XXXXXXXX">
  <input type="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: there is something still wrong :( can you please check this html file: http://sgscoc.aman-tech.com/NEW.HTML

Comment: Yes, see the source code - it shows `pattern="[a-zA-Z]2/\d4/\d2/\d8$"` while it should be `pattern="[a-zA-Z]{2}/\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{8}"`. There is some template handling issue. I have no idea what removes `{` and `}`, please check. Perhaps, you need to double the braces and use `{{` and `}}`. Or, to play it safe, just repeat the patterns: `pattern="[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]/\d\d\d\d/\d\d/\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d"`.

Answer (score 0):

pattern="^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]/\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{8}$"

Comment: explain: "won't accept it".  I'm not getting an error, are you?

Comment: I am getting HTML 5 Error, please match the requested format

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle for what you are seeing?

Comment: here is my fiddle, the TEXT input should be green when pattern is matched https://jsfiddle.net/ff1syanw/

Comment: you may also test the pattern in here http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_pattern

Comment: Your fiddle currently shows the text color as green, implying it is valid.  I'm not sure what outcome you are expecting.

Answer (score -1):

You need to escape the slashes.

```
/^[a-z]{2}\/\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{8}$/i
```

1. `^` start from the beginning
2. `[a-z]{2}` match any letter twice
3. `\/` match a forward slash
4. `\d{4}` match 4 digits
5. `\/` match a forward slash
6. `\d{2}` match 2 digits
7. `\/` match a forward slash
8. `\d{8}` match 8 digits
9. `$` match end

And use the `/i` regex option to specify case in-sensitive

Comment: No, the slashes should not be escaped. The pattern is sent as a string, and not as a regex literal. And you cannot use a regex literal in HTML5 pattern attribute.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Oh. My bad. I didn't realize where it was going.

Answer (score -2):

There is no "Regex"ing in HTML5!

You can do validations, etc. of your HTML page elements using javascript though!

Comment: I typed many patterns for HTML5 Regex, and the final example is here, but I have something wrong in the pattern,   <input tabindex="5" type="Text" name="description" size="19" required pattern="^[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z]\/\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{8}^"  placeholder="CC/YYYY/MM/XXXXXXXX"></td>

Comment: "There is no "Regex"ing in HTML5!" — False. https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-input-pattern

Comment: Update your question and add that you want it for input's `pattern` attribute.

Comment: @Uzbekjon read the question and you'll see that the example OP posted already included it in a pattern attribute.

Comment: Please check the COC NUmber filed in this html file: http://sgscoc.aman-tech.com/NEW.HTML